# What's the difference between "for a short time" and "in a short time"?

Tags: prepositions

I submitted the following simple sentence to my tutor, and she told me to replace "for" with "in":

> I really want to know about his business because he has made so much money for a short time

That is, she told me to replace *for a short time* with *in a short time*.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Greetings @Kyeong! I think you could have more success with the site: http://ell.stackexchange.com/. It is specifically for English Language Learners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*He made money [in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in) a short time* would almost always imply that he was working **within** a short framework of time to make money:

> 2 Expressing a period of time during which an event happens or a
>   situation remains the case:
>   *they met **in** 1885
>
>   at one o’clock **in** the morning
>
>   I hadn’t seen him **in** years*
>   <sub>*ODO **emphasis** added*</sub>

*He made money [for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for) a short time* might more likely imply that he worked to make money in order to **have** it or **use** it during a short framework of time:

> 10 Indicating the length of (a period of time):
>   *he was jailed **for** 12 years
>
>   I haven’t seen him **for** some time*
>   <sub>*ODO **emphasis** added*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your comment. then, you mean we can focus more on the shortness of the time by using "in", right? because "for" is used when we want to talk about the period.

Comment: Both expression focus on the *shortness of time*, but ***in*** describes one relationship to the short time, while ***for*** describes a different relationship to that short time. Sometimes *in a short time* and *for a short time* can be substituted for each other, and sometimes one sounds strange. Learning to use prepositions [**idiomatically**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idiomatic) takes lots of practice with people who have plenty of experience.

Comment: For me, the 'for' suggests that the mentioned period is over, while 'in' indicates that the business is still running and producing money,

Comment: @Thinkeye, *I **finished** writing my book **in** three months*: period is over. But *I have been writing my book **for** three months*: ongoing time frame. :-)

Comment: @John Please elaborate with respect to time forms used in the original question and in your comment. Please rewrite your comment using the present perfect as the original sentence does :-)

Answer (score 0):

"for a short time" has a very similar meaning to "for awhile or for a moment"
E.g., He has been asleep for a short time.
Compare the sentence with "He fell asleep in a short time."
In your case, it should be "in a short time".

Answer (score 0):

- 1 He solved the problem in five minutes.
- 2 He worked on the problem for hours, but could not solve it.

In 1 the idea is in what time did he solve the problem, how much time did he need.

In 2 the idea is how long did he work on the problem.

You say

- 3 We walked for hours, not in hours.